# Facing incorrect output while linking programs

Tags: unix

**I am having a trouble in calling the user defined functions in the main program, using unix. the program is executing only for the number generation in the main program. but when i call the predefined function . the output retrieved is incorrect. Can someone please correct me where i have done it wrong**

My main program states as

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sort1(int []);

int main(void) {

int array[100];
 int i , j;

 printf("ten random numbers in [1,1000]\n");

 for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
{
  generate random numbers
}

  printf("The list of Hundred random numbers are \n");

for (j = 1; j <= 10; j++ )
  {
     //to print the random numbers
  }

sort1(array);
return 0;
}


//this is my user defined function: sort1.c

include <stdio.h>

int sort1(int a[])
{
 int array[100], i, d, swap, e=10;

// algortithm
   }
 }

 printf("Sorted list in ascending order:\n");

 for ( i= 0 ; i< e ; i++ )
    printf("%d\n", array[i]);

}
```

**I get the output as**

```
ten random numbers in [1,1000]
The list of Hundred random numbers are
```

--This gives correct output
    Sorted list in ascending order:
    1
    -1442229816
    0
    -1444472964

Comment: You're sorting an indeterminate array, `array[100]`, a local variable in your `sort1` function with no definitive content whatsoever, leaving the passed in array `a[]` untouched. And the functions don't match (declared as `void sort1(int a[])`, implemented as `int sort1(a[])`. This shouldn't even *link*.

Comment: how can i correct this code in order to get expected output? should i change the the
void sort1(int []); to  int sort1(a[]) ; i am still not getting the output

Comment: For one, delete `array[100]` from the `sort()` function, then fix everything that breaks (and it will break almost the entire function, as everywhere `array` appears in that function should be `a` instead). The rest I leave to you. Btw, you never called `srand()` either to seed your random generator. May want to to that as well.

Comment: Great. When done it should look [something like this](http://ideone.com/QTQ1yr). Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sort1(int []);

int main(void) {
  int array[100];
  int i;

  printf("ten random numbers in [1,1000]\n");

  for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
  {
     array[i] = rand()%1000 + 1;
  }

  printf("The list of Hundred random numbers are \n");

  for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++ )
  {
   printf("Element[%d] = %d\n", i, array[i] );
  }
  //Up to here it's ok but you have set the values in the positions 1-10 of the array so keep consistent with it

  sort1(array);

  printf("Sorted list in ascending order:\n");

  for ( i= 1 ; i<= 10 ; i++ )
    printf("%d\n", array[i]);
  return 0;
}

void sort1(int a[])
{
   int i,swap,sorted=0;
   while(sorted==0){ //flag to know if array is sorted 0 means not sorted.
     sorted=1;  // we set the flag to sorted at start of sweep
     for (i= 1 ; i<= (10-1); i++)  //sweep through array
     {
        if (a[i] > a[i+1]) //check if sorted
        {
          swap   = a[i];
          a[i]   = a[i+1];
          a[i+1] = swap;
          sorted=0;  //if not sorted set flag to 0 and swap
        }
     }
   }
}
```

Main problems in your code:

1) array[100] is not initialized in sort1 function.

2) I do not understand your sorting algorithm but in any case you are checking for values of a[0] which are not initialized so take care of the array positions you use each time and be consistent with it.

3) function prototype does not match